# DTLB miss address trace using Intel PEBS

Tags: linux, performancecounter, perfmon, tlb, perf

I am trying to generate an address trace of D-TLB misses through use of hardware performance counters. Intel processors have "Precise Event Based Sampling" (PEBS) that can dump hardware register contents each time a sample is taken.  I need to use this register dump to create the addresses that caused the D-TLB miss. However, I am unsure how can I generate the address of the access from the register dump.

Does somebody has some experience in doing something similar and can give me some pointers on this?

Thanks

Arka

Comment: If you already has register dump at point of Sampling, you should: read $eip, find and decode the instruction at $eip, recalculate memory address using decoded instruction and register dump.

Answer (score -1):

Performance counters are basically counters, you want extra information that they don't supply. 
What you need is a tracer capable of capturing bus transactions, this could be a little hard to come by, and still won't be perfect as you would only catch misses that also missed the STLB (2nd level TLB), plus - their page walk stages didn't hit the cache, so you could have enough visibility to reconstruct the virtual addresses.
Your best bet, in my opinion, would be to simply run your code through a binary instrumentation tool (such as PIN, or szim), write a hook to capture all memory accesses - and run them through a callback that simulates a DTLB (you can use several uarch simulators or write some simple code for yourself). You just need to get the basic DTLB details of your system (size, associativity, etc..). That should give you a relatively close idea on what the DTLB missed addresses would be on the real system. Of course there could be complications here if you're using mixed-sized pages, or virtualization (god forbid..)